# Why does Base64.encode() not reset memory after being called?

Tags: memory-management, solidity

Ok, so this is my very first question on stack exchange and I am new to solidity.

I am trying to create an ERC 721 contract that emits a url containing the address and (hashed) tokenId of minted NFTs. I noticed that the URLs emitted become larger every time the mint function is called.

I narrowed down the problem to Base64.encode(), but am stuck. I searched but can't seem to find an answer, possibly because I do not know what to search for.

Take the contract below. It emits a custom URL that includes a data field created through Base64.encode(). I would expect the emitted URL to be the same length every time, as memory is wiped between calls.

But... each time the Mint function is called, the data field includes data from previous calls.

The first time I call Mint() the emitted reads as follows: "someURL.com?MHg5ZDgzZTE0MDMzMDc1OGE4ZmZkMDdmOGJkNzNlODZlYmNhOGE1Njky"

The second time I call Mint() the emitted is longer:
"someURL.com?MHg5ZDgzZTE0MDMzMDc1OGE4ZmZkMDdmOGJkNzNlODZlYmNhOGE1Njky?MHg5ZDgzZTE0MDMzMDc1OGE4ZmZkMDdmOGJkNzNlODZlYmNhOGE1Njky"

And on it goes evertime I call Mint(). Memory seems to be retained. Why? What am I missing here?

Many many thanks for any help or pointers!

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Strings.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Base64.sol";

contract URLMemory {
    using Strings for uint256;
    string customURL = "someURL.com";

    event CustomURLIssued(string customURL);

    function issueCustomURL() public returns (string memory){ 
        
        customURL = string(
            abi.encodePacked(
                customURL,
                "?",
                Base64.encode( abi.encodePacked( Strings.toHexString(address(this)) )
                )
            ));
            
        return customURL;
    }

    function Mint() public { 
        emit CustomURLIssued(issueCustomURL());
    }
}
```

Comment: I could not reproduce your issue. Possibly it's caused by something outside of this code - for example calling the `Mint()` function multiple times? ... I deployed your code in Remix, executed `Mint()` once - got 1 event log of `CustomURLIssued`. Executed `Mint()` again - and got another 1 event log of `CustomURLIssued`.

Comment: Just to clarify, I do get one log each time, but the output (customURL) becomes larger. The first time I call I get: "customURL": ""someURL.com?MHg5ZDgzZTE0MDMzMDc1OGE4ZmZkMDdmOGJkNzNlODZlYmNhOGE1Njky". The second time "customURL": "someURL.com?MHg5ZDgzZTE0MDMzMDc1OGE4ZmZkMDdmOGJkNzNlODZlYmNhOGE1Njky?MHg5ZDgzZTE0MDMzMDc1OGE4ZmZkMDdmOGJkNzNlODZlYmNhOGE1Njky". Note that the data part is duplicated second time around. This does not happen on your side?

Comment: Edited the question for clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
customURL = string(
    abi.encodePacked(
        customURL,
        "?",
        Base64.encode(abi.encodePacked(Strings.toHexString(address(this))))
    )
);
```

This snippet assigns a new value to `customURL`, and the new value consists of following parts:

- the previous value of `customURL`
- `?` string literal
- and the encoded address

So each time you execute this snippet, it effectively appends the `customURL` with the new values.

---

Simplified example when we omit the Base64 encoding.

```
customURL = string(
    abi.encodePacked(
        customURL,
        "?"
    )
);
```

Initial `customURL` value = `A`

After first run it becomes `A?`. Second run `A??`. Third run `A???`. And so on.

---

If you want to keep the `someURL.com` prefix and only add the `?` and encoded value for each token, you can just return the newly generated value without assigning it back to `customURL`.

```
function issueCustomURL() public view returns (string memory){ 
    return string(
        abi.encodePacked(
            customURL,
            "?",
            Base64.encode( abi.encodePacked( Strings.toHexString(address(this)) )
            )
        ));
}
```

---

Note: If you upgrade to Solidity 0.8.12 or later, you can use native function [string.concat()](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.12/types.html#bytes-and-string-as-arrays) instead of connecting the strings with `abi.encodePacked()`.

```
string.concat(customURL, "?", encoded)
```

Comment: This is indeed it. I was saving the variable in the contract storage and then kept on recalling it. Gosh. Thank you for helping out!